# mysql php if else inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT business_region FROM business WHERE business_category='occupation'");
// count the output amount
$businessCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($businessCount > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
      $business_region = $row["business_region"];          
      $Region_view .= "display value";
  }
}
```

This gives a following result:

> Michigan Toronto  Ohio  Manchester  London  Sydney  Paris

I want to select **only *`Ohio and London`***
as a variable value as:

`$Region_view .`

Perhaps I can use if else structure, but I could not get it to work.

i.e. I need to select ***only `Ohio, London`***

I can do it using joint MySQL statement but it is too slow so I need and ask for a different way.

Comment: Why only "Ohio, London"? Could you clarify your question a bit? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `if ($businessCount > 0)` - this if is absolutely useless

Comment: The slow operation is most likely the `DISTINCT` not adding `AND business_region IN ( 'Ohio', 'London' )` to the WHERE clause of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT business_region FROM business WHERE business_category ='occupation'");
// count the output amount
$businessCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if ($businessCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $business_region = $row["business_region"];         
    if ($business_region == 'Ohio' || $business_region == 'London') // added
    $Region_view .= $business_region;//changed
  }
}
```

Comment: [Indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)? :)

Comment: @AndréLaszlo his own, will be industry standard in 2015

Comment: @Najzero May God fulfill all your wishes.

Comment: Great!!! it works perfect well done mate

Comment: @user3106822 You should mark it as accepted for others to know that it works perfectly.